# Proving there is a minimally strong digraph with $n$ vertices and $m$ arcs for all $n,m\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $2\leq n\leq m\leq 2n−2$?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, directed-graphs

Given any relation $A\subseteq V^2$ a digraph $D=(V,A)$ is minimally strong *iff* $D$ is strongly connected and for every arc $a\in A$ the digraph $D−a=(V,A\setminus\{a\})$ is not strongly connected.

With that said is there a simple way to prove for all $n,m\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $2\leq n\leq m\leq 2n−2$ there always exist at least one minimally strong digraph with $n$ vertices and $m$ arcs?

---

When $2\leq m=n$ we can construct a cycle with $n$ vertices which is minimally strong and has $m$ arcs whereas if we have $2\leq m=2n-2$ we can take a tree graph with $n$ vertices and replace each edge $\{u,v\}$ with the arcs $(u,v)$ and $(v,u)$ to similarly get a minimally strong digraph with exactly $m$ arcs and $n$ vertices. But what if $n<m< 2n-2$? How can I find a clean way to prove this in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $n<m<2n-2$, write
$$m=2(m-n)+(2n-m)\,.$$
We see that $2n-m\geq 3$.  Now construct an oriented cycle $C$ on $2n-m$ vertices.  Form a tree using one vertex of $C$ and the remaining $m-n\geq 1$ vertices.  Then the digraph is minimally strong, and it has exactly $n$ vertices and $m$ arcs.

Comment: Was just thinking up the same thing by attaching a path to a cycle